# Configuration Getting Ignored in Test

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing, keycloak

I try to test my spring app but encounter following problem:
In "normal mode"(mvn spring-boot:run) the app starts as expected and `adapterConfig` gets set and is NOT NULL. When I start my testclass to test the MVC, `adapterConfig` does not get set. Spring ignores the whole config class.

test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = StudentController.class)
public class StudentControllerTests {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @MockBean
    private StudentService service;
    @MockBean
    private StudentRepository repository;
    @Test
    public void shouldReturnABC() throws Exception{
        MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/students/abc")).andReturn();
    }
}
```

controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/students")
@PermitAll
public class StudentController {
    @Autowired
    StudentService studentService;
    //get
    @GetMapping("/abc")
    public String abc (){
        return "abc";
    }
```

config:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringBootKeycloakConfigResolver implements KeycloakConfigResolver {
    private KeycloakDeployment keycloakDeployment;
    private AdapterConfig adapterConfig;
    @Autowired
    public SpringBootKeycloakConfigResolver(AdapterConfig adapterConfig) {
        this.adapterConfig = adapterConfig;
    }
    @Override
    public KeycloakDeployment resolve(OIDCHttpFacade.Request request) {
        if (keycloakDeployment != null) {
            return keycloakDeployment;
        }
        keycloakDeployment = KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(adapterConfig);
        return keycloakDeployment;
    }
}
```

adapterConfig is `null` when hitting the test but gets set & created when hitting it the normal way, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using @WebMvcTest, the container will inject only components related to Spring MVC (@Controller, @ControllerAdvice, etc.) not the full configuration use @SpringBootTest with @AutoConfigureMockMvc instead.

[Spring Boot Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html)

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to exclude the JPA from the context now?

Answer (score 1):

Keycloak's AutoConfiguration is not included by `@WebMvcTest`.

You could

1. Include it manually via `@Import(org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfiguration.class)`
2. Or use `@SpringBootTest`

Answer (score 0):

with spring boot 2.5 i had I had to import `KeycloakAutoConfiguration` into my test.

```
@WebMvcTest(value = ApplicationController.class, properties = "spring.profiles.active:test")
@Import(KeycloakAutoConfiguration.class)
public class WebLayerTest { 
        // ... test code ....
}
```